# Bundle Leaflet for use in Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browserify, require

I would like to use leaflet to load a custom map on a simple local website.

Currently I'm using Node Js, Express, EJS (as template engine) but I can't seem to be able to use leaflet. I've tried also using browserify and importing the bundle.js script but still no luck.

Any idea on how I could do that?

```js
//map.js

var map = L.map("map-panel");

var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmAttrib = 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
var mapLayer = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 20, attribution: osmAttrib });

map.addLayer(mapLayer).fitWorld();
//map.setView([location.lat, location.lon], 13);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
</head> 

<body>
<div id="map-panel">
</div>
   <!--    <script src="bundle.js"></script> -->
    <script src="/js/map_panel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As per the import, I've tried both in app.js or map.js with `var L = require('leaflet');`

or in the controller var L = require('leaflet');

I used to get this ReferenceError: L is not defined. The line is referring to the first js line.

Now I tried with using browserify and I get "window is not defined" error.
I was trying to follow this tutorial http://mappingandco.com/blog/leaflet-with-browserify-basic-tutorial/

Thanks for any help or suggestion!

Comment: The place to start would be to post the code that you tried, and what happened when you tried it (error messages and other output.)  See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you Matt, I thought it wouldn't have been necessary but now I added them.

Comment: I can't see `leaflet.js` getting loaded - that would account for `L` being undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `require()` anything natively in the browser, but Browserify or Webpack will let you bundle modules in to your code so it can be run in a browser.

You should write your JavaScript code with `require` statements, then *build* it to produce a JavaScript *bundle* that you deliver to the browser with the HTML.  Every time you change your code, you'll need to rebuild, or add a [watcher](https://github.com/browserify/watchify) to your project and let the watcher run the rebuild. It's important to understand that it's `bundle.js` that gets called by the HTML, **not** `app.js`. The code you posted above hasn't been bundled and won't work for that reason.

Also, the code you posted above doesn't seem to actually add anything visible except zoom controls to the map.

Using the tutorial code, I've posted a working example below:

## directory structure

```
project
  node_modules/
  app.js
  package.json
  index.html
  dist/
    bundle.js
    style.css
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "leaf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "browserify app.js -o dist/bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.3.1"
  }
}
```

## app.js

```
// require modules
var L = require('leaflet');
var $ = require('jquery');
// Create the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([41.3921, 2.1705], 13);

// Indicate leaflet the specific location of the images folder that it needs to render the page
L.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/'

// Use OpenStreetMap tiles and attribution
var osmTiles = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var attribution = '© OpenStreetMap contributors';

// Create the basemap and add it to the map
L.tileLayer(osmTiles, {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: attribution
}).addTo(map);

// Add some geojson from this URL
var geojsonURL = 'http://mappingandco.github.io/geojsonDB/barcelona/neighbourhoods.geojson'

$.getJSON(geojsonURL, function(neighbourhoods) {
  L.geoJson(neighbourhoods, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.NBarri);
    }
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Leaflet with browserify template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## install and build

```
npm install
npm run build
```

Then open the `index.html` file in your browser and you should see a map.

Comment: Thank you so much, Matt, for the detailed explanation. 
I've tried it and it works perfectly!

Now will try to put it together with an express server!
Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Awesome.  Glad it helped!

Comment: Please use url `https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` see: https://github.com/openstreetmap/operations/issues/737